# Unable to load fixture data in Django tests

Tags: python, django, testing, django-admin

I have an app called pta.apps.users which is loaded in the Loaded apps setting in my settings.py.

The app works fine, I now want to test it and have placed json files in the fixtures directory inside my users app.

I have a test which runs fine but the fixtures wont load.

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.test.client import Client
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

class SimpleTest(TestCase):

  fixtures = ['user.json']

  def setUp(self):
    self.c = Client()

  def test_parse_html(self):
    response = self.c.get('/users/login/', follow=True)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)
    self.assertEquals(soup.h1.renderContents(), 'Entrance')
```

I just get `No fixtures found.` in my output. I am using Django 1.2.1. Any help would be appreciatted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To load a fixture, I'm pretty sure you have to either call it manually with `loaddata` (like you did), or call it specifically "initial_data," e.g. `initial_data.sql`, `initial_data.json`, `initial_data.yaml`, etc., and store it in the fixtures directory of your app.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/#automatically-loading-initial-data-fixtures

Answer (score 1):

where did you placed your fixtures?
The fixtures should placed in your app directory:

```
MyApp/fixtures/user.json
```

Or you hav to specify a external fixtures directory in your settings.py:

```
FIXTURE_DIRS = (
    'external_fixtures/',
)
```

Comment: yes that is where I have them MyApp/fixtures/user.json

Cheers

Richard

Comment: what is weird is that I can load data directly from loaddata using python manage.py loaddata user.json